# How to increase loading speed of image thumbs from device

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am displaying image thumbs in grid view using content resolver.

**Question:** It runs properly on my device with 50 images but on my other device it hangs. How I can reduce the loading time and increase the app speed.

My Activity in which I am displaying thumbs using Base Adapter is as follows

```
public class CustomGallaryViewActivity extends Activity {

Context mContext;

ArrayList<ImageItem> imageList;
private int listCount;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_gallary_view);


    mContext=this;
    imageList=CreateImageThumbnails.createThumbnails(CustomGallaryViewActivity.this);
    listCount=imageList.size();
    GridView imageGrid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    imageAdapter=new ImageAdapter();
    imageGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater infalter=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=infalter.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem,null);
        holder.imageview=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageview.setId(position);
    holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id = v.getId();
            Log.d("IDIDID",""+id);
            ImageItem item = imageList.get(id);
            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,FullScreenImageActivtiy.class);
            //intent.putExtra("ID",item.id);
            intent.putExtra("ImageItemVal",new int[]{item.id,item.imgNumber,listCount,id});
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    ImageItem item=new ImageItem();

    item=imageList.get(position);

    holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(item.img);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_gallary_view, menu);
    return true;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
}
```

}

I am creating thumb list using following class

```
public class CreateImageThumbnails{

public static ArrayList<ImageItem> createThumbnails(Activity refActivtiy){

    ArrayList<ImageItem> thumbNails=new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    //Cursor imageCursor=refActivtiy.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,null,null,orderBy);
    Cursor imageCursor = refActivtiy.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,null, null,orderBy);
    if(imageCursor!=null){
    int count=imageCursor.getCount();
    Log.d("Count Vlaue",""+count);
    int image_column_index=imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

    for(int i=0;i < count;i++){
        imageCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id=imageCursor.getInt(image_column_index);

        Log.d("Image ID : ",""+id);
        ImageItem imageItem=new ImageItem();

        imageItem.id=id;
        imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                refActivtiy.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
      thumbNails.add(imageItem);

    }

    }

    return thumbNails;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pass the cursor object returned by this code and problem is solved...

```
    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,null, null,orderBy);
```